# YII Change the default language

Tags: php, yii

I'm a beginner in YII framework (PHP)
When creating a new site with YII, it will displayed with english page.

I want to change the default language to French, so pages will be displayed in French.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To change the language, set [`CApplication::language`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#language-detail) appropriately. This can be done at runtime as in

```
Yii::app()->language = 'fr';
```

but usually it's done in your [application configuration](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.application#application-configuration):

```
array(
    // ...settings...
    'language' => 'fr',
    // ...more settings...
)
```

Comment: thx you for ure answer
can you specify in any config file should i put this ?

Comment: @user1288058: I have given a link to the relevant section of the Yii definitive guide. If you hope to do anything at all with Yii you should make sure to read it.

Comment: I have added  'language' => 'fr',  to protected/config/main.php and there is no change

Comment: @user1288058: You know that [you have to output localized text using `Yii::t` and provide the french translations yourself](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.i18n), right?

Comment: yes of course, but here, i'm talking about core messages of YII, for exemple validation error messages and other text generated by the framework, I have googled and i foud that there is a folder under 'framework' called 'I18N' containing all core message with different language.
the problem that i'm faceing is how to activate frensh language

Answer (score 5):

and so you can set the default languages in the config/main.php as

```
return array(
    ...
    'sourceLanguage' => 'fr',
    'language'=>'en',
    ...
    'params' => array(
               ...
               'languages'=>array('en_us'=>'English', 'fr'=>'French', 'fa_ir'=>'فارسی'),
               ....
               ), 
);
```

and change your language everywhere you like:

```
Yii::app()->language = Yii::app()->params->languages['fa_ir'];
```

or more:

```
Yii::app()->language = Yii::app()->params->languages[$_GET['lang']];
```

Comment: Where is the part where it changes the language to French?

Comment: You can define it in protected/config/main.php
'params' => array(
               ...
               'languages'=>array('en_us'=>'English', 'fr'=>'French', 'fa_ir'=>'فارسی'),
is that ok?

Comment: The question is asking how to change the default language to French. Could you update your answer to reflect this?

Comment: in protected/config/main.php file add 'language'=>'fr'.
Is that OK?

Comment: That's more like it but can you click the edit button under your answer and add the additional information there. Not everyone checks the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Setting default language (in which your application is written in) can be configured trough `CApplication::sourceLanguage`, changing `CApplication::language` has no effect because it is set to en_en by default.

also when setting language you should be using localeID - fr_FR ;)

Answer (score 0):

location for Yii2: root/config/web.php and add this: **'language' => 'fr',**

```
    $config = [
      'id' => 'basic',
      'language' => 'fr', // Add this in config/web.php
      'basePath' => dirname( __DIR__ ),
      'bootstrap' => ['log'],
      ...
      ...
   ];
```